Бот перестал отвечать на сообщения, ошибку код не выдает
После переписывания кода с aiogram 2 на aiogram 3 бот перестал отвечать на сообщения, ошибку код не выдает.
Aiogram 3
import time
import aiogram
from aiogram import types, Router
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton,InputFile
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot
import asyncio
import datetime
from pyexpat.errors import messages
from aiogram.filters import Command

print('запуск бота')
time.sleep(1)
print(f'бот запущен')
dp = Dispatcher()
bot = Bot(token='')
router = Router()


@router.message(Command("start"))
async def start_message(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'{message.from_user.full_name}, для пользования ботом необходимо пройти CAPTCHA', reply_markup=verificathion)
"""у меня еще много кода, если будет нужен я скину"""
async def poolling():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(poolling())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('бот отключен')

Aiogram 2
import time
import aiogram
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton,InputFile
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot
import asyncio
import datetime
from gevent.libev.corecext import callback
from pyexpat.errors import messages

print('запуск бота')
time.sleep(1)
print(f'бот запущен')
bot = Bot(token='')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def start_message(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'{message.from_user.full_name}, для пользования ботом необходимо пройти CAPTCHA', reply_markup=verificathion)

async def poolling():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(poolling())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('бот отключен')


Добавьте код aiogram2, что бы было с чем сравнивать "было" -> "стало"

я сегодня по случайности обновил aiogram до 3 версии и теперь сижу ничего не понимая, все говорят переходить на 3 версию, вот и перешел получается =)

Вы забыли (или не знали) подключить роутер.
Вот как нужно сделать:
async def poolling():
    # Добавьте сюда остальные роутеры, если они есть
    dp.include_routers(router, ) 

    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(poolling())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('бот отключен')

Должно помочь. Вот ссылка на гайд/пример проекта на aiogram v3 с применением роутера

Спасибо, все заработало!

@Inkera, если ответ решил ваш вопрос, пожалуйста, нажмите галочку зеленую
